# EF Core on Npgsql AddRange indices

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have to copy a collection of recodrs and add them to a db with new Ids.

```
var subEntities= ct.SubEntities.Where(qf => qf.ParentEntityId == oldParentEntityId).ToList();
subEntities.ForEach(qf => { qf.ParentEntityId = newParentEntityId; qf.Id = default(int); });
ct.SubEntities.AddRange(subEntities);
```

When `AddRange` has run all entities `subEntities` has awkward Ids like -2147482647 and they go into db though there is a correct sequence. How to fix it?

My entity classes and mapping:

```
public class SubEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
    //props
}

public class ParentEntity 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SubEntity> SubEntities { get; set; }
    //props
}

//OnModelCreating
builder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
    .HasMany(q => q.SubEntities)
    .WithOne(qf => qf.ParentEntity)
    .HasForeignKey(qf => qf.ParentEntityId)
    .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: Have you tried to create new instances with Select method ? I need to know about your entities' mapping, can you post that code please ?

Comment: @H.Herzl Yes, I just tried to select new instances from source collection and AddRange them - all the same.

Comment: I need to see the fulll code to save changes, can you post ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way the `ParentEntity` were extracted. It were tracked by EF (so did the `SubEntities` too I suppose), so I tried to add a collection already being tracked. I don't quite understand how EF works in this case but the  solution was:

```
var subEntities= ct.SubEntities
    .Where(qf => qf.ParentEntityId == oldParentEntityId)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```